# Preventing ctrl+z in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I used the code sample below to disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> and it works. I used similar mechanics to disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> (undo) in the browser but it doesn't work.

```
var ctrlDown = false;
var ctrlKey = 17, vKey = 86, cKey = 67, zKey = 90;

$('body').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 17 || e.keyCode == 91) {
    ctrlDown = true;
  };
}).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 17 || e.keyCode == 91) {
    ctrlDown = false;
  };
});

$("body").keydown(function(e){
  if ((ctrlDown && e.keyCode == zKey) || (ctrlDown && e.keyCode == vKey) || (ctrlDown && e.keyCode == cKey)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: This code prevents Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in my tests. http://jsfiddle.net/xg3z2p5o/

Comment: What is the point of this? Your code won't make the *Edit* menu disappear, so none of these actions will be disabled. You're just making a nuisance of yourself.

Comment: doesn't make sense using multiple handlers for the same event either

Comment: @squeamishossifrage It's for a code battle game. There is a feature in the code editor to shuffle the code ten times. It's a lot harder/slower to click undo in edit menu than to ctrl+z for undo.

Comment: @charlietfl I found these from sample codes on stackoverflow and haven't bothered reefactoring it. If you think you can use a single handler then feel free to post your refactored version

Comment: @apollo And making things harder/slower for your users is a good thing because why? Couldn't you try writing a game that doesn't require you to hijack the standard interface behaviour?

Comment: instead of blocking default behaviour, why don't you make your custom input, by listening to keydown and only allowing the actions you want?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage You don't know their use case. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site NOT a question and argue site. There are many valid reasons. The goal of the site is to answer the question. I have a specific use case where CTRL+Z is causing undesired behavior. So this question is valid for me.

Comment: As of right now, I don't even see an Undo option in any menu in Chrome. Valid reason to disable is to let user undo actions that aren't tracked by browser. The default behavior is removed in a variety of major web text editors https://github.com/w3c/editing/issues/150

Answer (score 0):

I can see from testing that the if condition in your $("body").keydown handler isn't firing. While ctrlDown does get set to `true`, for some reason your series of conditions isn't firing. I don't think storing key codes and ctrl state in the global scope is going to be a great approach.

Rather than a separate handler testing for ctrl usage, it'd be easier to test just within the "z" keydown handler for whether Ctrl (or Meta i.e. command, to be Mac-compatible as well) is being used. The `event` object has Boolean properties `ctrlKey` and `metaKey` for just such occasions. So your code would be:

```
$("body").keydown(function(e){
  var zKey = 90;
  if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.key == 'z') {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

This is still not quite as robust as it could be, since you'd want to only check metaKey on Mac and check ctrl on Linux/Windows to handle a few edge cases where someone might press "Meta + Z" (does that do anything in Windows?), but it's close. It works on my Mac.

---

A caution—& you've probably already considered this—that disabling OS-level keyboard shortcuts can be really dangerous. It messes with user expectations in a bad way. If you're overriding to do something similar in a big browser app, that makes perfect sense, though. Be careful!