# Disable Chrome's text input undo/redo (CTRL+Z / CTRL+Y)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, undo, textinput

i'm currently developing a web application and i encounter a problem.
As you might know or not, chrome has a feature that gives `<input>` (especially text inputs) an "undo" function when you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and "redo" with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> it may seem like a good feature in normal websites, but currently i'm making an image editor that also uses those keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> & <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>).

in my app i also have a text input, so when i change the text input's content and then hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo the changes in my image editor, it would undo the change in the text editor instead!

here is a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anandhiya23/full/LRzpWE/) that would demonstrate the effect
(instruction is in the Codepen)

So in conclusion i want to remove the undo/redo function in chrome how can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var ctrlDown = false;
var ctrlKey = 17, vKey = 86, cKey = 67, zKey = 90;

document.body.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 17 || e.keyCode == 91) {
    ctrlDown = true;
  }
  if ((ctrlDown && e.keyCode == zKey) || (ctrlDown && e.keyCode == vKey) || (ctrlDown && e.keyCode == cKey)) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
document.body.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 17 || e.keyCode == 91) {
    ctrlDown = false;
  };
};
```

```html
<body>
    <input type='text' value='test' />
</body>
```

Does this work?

Stolen from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xg3z2p5o/), found on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150987/preventing-ctrlz-in-browser) as a comment by @KadeHafen.

Comment: Ah! i have used `e.preventDefault` before but it doesn't work for me.. is it because i used `keypress` and not `keydown`?

Comment: @Bintang I think that using `keypress` probably was the issue for you, as it does not seem to work if I change it in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could use onkeydown event, and preventDefault.. eg.

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'z') {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("CTRL + Z!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I like this and it works in IE11 and Chrome.  :) However, Undo is still available in the context-menu in both IE11 & Chrome, so additional work will be required to disable that too:(  I did this:    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'z') {
    return false;
   }

Comment: This is great. And I'd like to point out that I was able to do the event.preventDefault in a function fed to a window.addEventListener('keydown'). Likely because we're still getting the same event. Not an image editor in my case but a ThreeJS 3D scene that has undo history/steps and when it reached the end of the history it would auto switch over to text inputs and start deleting them.

Comment: If you want to retain the undo/redo functionality on just the text area components, do something like `e.ctrlKey && e.key.toLowerCase() === 'z' && e.target.tagName !== "TEXTAREA"`.