# Modify undo/redo behaviour on a textarea/menu in electron

Tags: textarea, electron

I devel electron application.
An application that edits a UML sequence diagram using canvas and multiple textarea.
Since textarea on the window takes Undo (Ctrl + z), Undo on Electron's Menu will not be called.
How can I invalidate the textarea's Undo and pass Control + z to the Electron's Menu?

## Steps to reproduce

Register Undo (Ctrl + z) in Electron's Menu.
Create application screen including textarea.
Launch application.
Edit textarea.
(Without focus on textarea) Press Ctrl + z.

## What I expected to see

Undo in Electron's Menu is called.

## What I saw instead

The focus moves to the textarea.
The contents of textarea are undoed.
Undo in Electron's Menu is not called.

## Other

[Disable Chrome's text input undo/redo (CTRL+Z / CTRL+Y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802159/disable-chromes-text-input-undo-redo-ctrlz-ctrly) was not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem today. I think it's a bug in electron that they don't override the native ctrl + z and ctrl + y of input fields when an accelerator is set.

I found a workaround with this hack:

```js
let zDown = false;
let zFired = false;
let yDown = false;
let yFired = false;
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        if (e.key === 'z') {
            zDown = true;
        }
        else if (e.key === 'y') {
            yDown = true;
        }
    }
};
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'z' && zDown) {
        if (!zFired) {
            menu.getMenuItemById('undo').click();
        }
        zDown = zFired = false;
    }
    else if (e.key === 'y' && yDown) {
        if (!yFired) {
            menu.getMenuItemById('redo').click();
        }
        yDown = yFired = false;
    }
};

let menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([{
    "label": "Edit",
    "submenu": [{
        "id": "undo",
        "label": "Undo",
        "accelerator": "CmdOrCtrl + z",
        click: () => {
            zFired = true;
            app.undo();
        }
    }, {
        "id": "redo",
        "label": "Redo",
        "accelerator": "CmdOrCtrl + y",
        click: () => {
            yFired = true;
            app.redo();
        }
    }]
}]);
```

It's dirty, but it works.

Comment: Thanks. my fix is

    //! snatching keys html input/textarea elements
    document.onkeydown = function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'z') {
            // Ctrl+z(Undo) textarea
            e.preventDefault();

            let current_doc = daisy.get_current_doc();
            if(null !== current_doc){
                Doc.undo(current_doc);
            }
        }
    }