# Override browser "undo" key command in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, undo

I'm creating an application with undo/redo functionality, and would like to utilize keyboard shortcut functionality to trigger this behavior, e.g. cmd+Z

Per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values), it appears possible to bind to the "Undo" key event.

My current code looks like this.

```
document.onkeydown = checkKey;

function checkKey(e) {
    if (e.key === "Undo") {
        e.preventDefault();
        undo();
    }
```

But it's still triggering the browser's default undo action (which in the case of Arc goes to a different tab).

Elsewhere on StackOverflow, [I see some old solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150987/preventing-ctrlz-in-browser) involving using `keyup` and `keydown` for specific `event.keycode`s, which works for me... but per MDN those are deprecated and I'd like to avoid it if possible. Wondering if there's a better, modern solution using `e.key`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you having a problem with your custom code not getting executed when you use e.key === "Undo"?  Or is it that the default browser Undo action cannot be prevented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", checkKey);

function checkKey(e) {
    // Check for the appropriate key combination for undo (e.g., Command/Ctrl + Z)
    if ((e.metaKey || e.ctrlKey) && e.key === "z") {
        e.preventDefault();
        undo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Disappointed there isn't a way to utilize the actual 'e.key === "Undo"' value, since this feels like its intended purpose... but accepting the answer since it works for me and avoids deprecated e.keycode .